# pytest customize sys.argv parsing

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to customize pytest command line option parsing behavior to accept two groups of paramaters separated by `--`.

1. parameters that come before the separator as passed to pytest as is.
2. The parameters after the separator are to be stored in fixture for later use

For example in the following invocation,

```
pytest -s mytest.py -- --myarg 10
```

`-s` option is passed to pytest and the string `--myarg 10` is stored as test_args fixture in `mytest.py`.

I have tried to customize `pytest_load_initial_conftests` to modify `args`.

```
% ls
args_plugin.py test_my_arg.py
% cat args_plugin.py
import pytest
from typing import List

_test_args: List[str] = []


def _setup_args(args: List[str]):
    sep = "--"
    if sep in args:
        idx = args.index("--")
        global _test_args
        _test_args = args[idx + 1 :]
        args = args[:idx]
    return args


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_load_initial_conftests(early_config, parser, args: List[str]):
    args = _setup_args(args)
    print(_test_args, args)
    outcome = yield


@pytest.fixture
def cli_args() -> List[str]:
    return _test_args

% cat test_my_args.py
import pytest


def test_cli_args(cli_args):
    print(cli_args)
```

Running it, I get following error

```
 % PYTHONPATH=. pytest -p args_plugin  -s . -- --myarg 10
['--myarg', '10'] ['-p', 'args_plugin', '-s', '.']
======= test session starts =======
collected 0 items

======= no tests ran in 0.00s =======
ERROR: file or directory not found: --myarg
```

Any alternative approaches to the problem are also welcome.

Comment: Did you look at [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) ?

Comment: Agree with @MauriceMeyer: Did you add [`parser.addoption` like explained in the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code right, I believe all you need is to add `[:]` to your `args =` expression in hook function.

Like this:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_load_initial_conftests(early_config, parser, args: List[str]):
    args[:] = _setup_args(args)
    print(_test_args, args)
    outcome = yield
```

It will overwrite `args` variable instead of defining new one (in local function scope)